# Dijkstra source to destination shortest path in directed, weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode, dijkstra, shortest-path

In the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) on Dijkstra, I am informed that if destination is known, I can terminate the search after line `13`. I don't get this, how do I terminate the search after line `13`?

```
1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
2
3      dist[source] ← 0                       // Distance from source to source
4      prev[source] ← undefined               // Previous node in optimal path initialization
5
6      create vertex set Q
7
8      for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
9          if v ≠ source:                      // v has not yet been removed from Q (unvisited nodes)
10             dist[v] ← INFINITY             // Unknown distance from source to v
11             prev[v] ← UNDEFINED            // Previous node in optimal path from source
12         add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
13     
14     while Q is not empty:
15         u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Source node in the first case
16         remove u from Q 
17         
18         for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
19             alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
20             if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
21                 dist[v] ← alt 
22                 prev[v] ← u 
23
24     return dist[], prev[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is wrong, the right line is `16` in that algorithm. An edit probably spoiled the line numbers or the paragraph below them.

What the paragraph meant is that if you're only interested in the shortest path from vertex S to Q, you can safely get out of the loop when Q is found since any other path will have a cost higher to reach it. Pseudocode follows

```
8    for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
9        if v ≠ source:                      // v has not yet been removed from Q (unvisited nodes)
10            dist[v] ← INFINITY             // Unknown distance from source to v
11            prev[v] ← UNDEFINED            // Previous node in optimal path from source
12        add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
13      
14    while Q is not empty:
15        u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Source node in the first case
16        remove u from Q 
17          
(extra)   if u == destination_point then break loop
```

When you encounter the end point Q, you can safely skip the update part where you update any adjacent vertex with a shortest path to reach it -> you've already found your destination. To reconstruct the path simply reverse walk the vector `prev` from `destination_point` to the source.

More details and a C++ example [here](http://marcodiiga.github.io/shortest-path/)

Comment: thanks marco, would you mind posting an update on the pseudocode here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some code after line 17:

```
1   function Dijkstra(Graph, source, destination):
2   
3       dist[source] ← 0                       // Distance from source to source
4       prev[source] ← undefined               // Previous node in optimal path initialization
5   
6       create vertex set Q
7   
8       for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
9           if v ≠ source:                      // v has not yet been removed from Q (unvisited nodes)
10              dist[v] ← INFINITY             // Unknown distance from source to v
11              prev[v] ← UNDEFINED            // Previous node in optimal path from source
12          add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
13      
14      while Q is not empty:
15          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Source node in the first case
16          remove u from Q 
17  
18          if source = destination:
19             return dist[], prev[]               // Valid only for destination vertex and vertex with lower distance
20         
21          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
22              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
23              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
24                  dist[v] ← alt 
25                  prev[v] ← u 
26  
27      return dist[], prev[]
```

Comment: fair enough, but we can't compare source = destination as source never changes. Perhaps you meant if u = destination?

Comment: and why would you choose to return at that point vs break out of the loop. As there is a return statement at the end already, we can save an extra line of code

Comment: Yes of course, I mean `if u = destination`, and replace `return` by `break` is good idea.